# videogame "longplay" translation

Tags: video-games

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longplay_(video_games)

Would a good translation of "Longplay" be "攻略"? It seems to be used in a similar way, but just about the only translation I could find was from this tweet:

`ドラゴンクエストⅢ 神龍攻略 （LongPlay of Dragon Warrior3 1080P）`(https://twitter.com/162La/status/1279030551509258240)

Answer (score 3):

攻略 in gaming contexts refers to any "attacking" or "how to" articles/movies, regardless of its length. For example, a 神龍攻略動画 can be any movie (short or long) where someone tries to defeat 神龍 or teach others how to defeat it. All those game wikis available online are also fundamentally 攻略サイト full of 攻略記事.

I don't think there is a catchy short phrase that directly matches that definition of longplay in Wikipedia. You probably have to explain descriptively depending on your intent, like 全編完全攻略動画, 資料用プレイ動画, 全編コメントなしウォークスルー, 実況なしプレイ動画.

Comment: shoot, I just assumed 神龍 was part of the game title.


seems like ロングプレイ is also used with considerable rarity; 

searching google videos for '"mario" "longplay"' gives About 199,000 results, while '”マリオ”　”ロングプレイ”' gives About 268 results.

Comment: @ORTA I believe ロングプレイ is not recognized even by core gamers. There are some videos titled ロングプレイ動画, but they are "ロング + プレイ動画", not "ロングプレイ + 動画". Some are shorter than 10 minutes, so they clearly don't match the definition of *longplay* in English :)